# Vlookup for data

Tags: excel, vlookup, validation, vba

Say I have two Sheets 1 & 2.

```
Sheet 1 has Column A: Apt No; Column B: House No; Column C: Key No
Sheet 2 has Column A: Apt No; Column B: House No; Column C: Key No
```

I want to do a vlookup for Sheet 1 – Column C: Key No. Whenever I enter an Apt No or House No in Sheet 1 then Key No shows up on Sheet 1 from Info in Sheet 2.
My formula for Column C: Key No of Sheet 1 is

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$5,3,FALSE),"")
```

How do I get it reference B2 as well?

Comment: so, you need to get `key no`, based on both `Apt No` and `House No`?

Comment: @Simoco Either one, not both.

Comment: so, formula should tries to find `key no` based on `Apt No`, if nothing found, then based on `House No`?

Comment: @Simoco So now if have Apt No info it pulls the relevant Key No from Sheet2. But if I enter House no, then it does not pull data in Key No. My Sheet 2 Data is as follows `Apt No House No Key No
1A  1
 1AA 2
2A  3
 2AA 4
`

Comment: still unclear to me, but is it what you need: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$5,3,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$5,3,FALSE),""))`?

Comment: @simoco Sorry my data there was confusing. In Sheet 2, If House no is present then there will be no data in Apt No and vice versa. So House no and Apt no will have unique key no.

Comment: @simoco Sorry I could not be more clear with my question. However the excel snapshot posted by Bobby below is correct but in Sheet 1, Column C & D are combined into 1. Please let me know if it makes sense :)

Comment: in that case this one should work: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$5,3,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$B$2:$C‌​$5,2,FALSE),""))`

Comment: @simoco This works like a charm. I know it was something simple but only a genius can figure the simple stuff out :)

Comment: @simoco Had a question for you. How do you put excels in questions. I could not find any info in the instructions. Can you please let me know.

Comment: what do you mean by `excels`? screenshots or workbook? i fworkbook, you could upload it (e.g. using https:\\www.dropbox.com) and paste a link. If screenshot - see this guide: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/how-do-i-post-a-screenshot-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As follow up from comments to Q, this one works:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$5,3,FALSE),
          IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$B$2:$C‌​‌​$5,2,FALSE),""))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can double nest the IFERROR.

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$5,3,FALSE),VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$5,3,FALSE))),"")
```

Checks value of A2, if that errors, checks B2, and if that errors returns an error to the upper iferror, which returns the "".

edit *opps I see someone else already suggested this. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

It may make more sense for you to use a =concatenate function to combine your first and second column into a new column. You would then use this column as your lookup criteria, since chances are, no (or not many of) records in your sheet will have identical apartment numbers AND houce numbers.

This would look something like:

```
=VLOOKUP([new concatenated column],Sheet2!$A$2:$C$5,3,FALSE)
```

Hope this helps, if I missed the mark please let me know and I can try my best to elaborate.

Comment: I tried this but does not work. I'll try to explain my issue better. The problem i'm facing with my formula is when I enter house No in Sheet 1, it does not pull the relevant key no info from sheet 2. But if I enter the Apt No info then it pulls relevant key no from Sheet 2.Each House and Apt number in Sheet 2 will have a unique key No

Comment: I would nest the =iferror, so do this: =IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$5,3,FALSE),VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$5,3,FALSE

Answer (score 1):

**The logic is**:

- Put in value for *Apt No* (in Sheet1) and use VLOOKUP to find *Key No* (from Sheet2)

  OR
- If *Apt No* not available as input, put in *House No* (in Sheet1) and use VLOOKUP to find *Key No* (from Sheet2)

On **Sheet1.Range("C2") paste in this code**:

```
    =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$5,3,FALSE),"")
```

On **Sheet1.Range("D2") paste in this code**:

```
    =IFERROR((IF(C2="", VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$B$2:$C$5,2,FALSE),"")),"")
```

Once pasted into the cells, copy and drag to fill in formulas for the two columns.

---

[image: Sheet1]
[image: Sheet2]

---

**UPDATE:**

If you want to just do it where only three columns are visible in *Sheet1*, I would just insert a new column called *Key No* and paste in the following code for Range("C2"):

```
=IF(D2<>"", D2, E2)
```

This is just saying if D2 is not an empty string, use it as the value.  Otherwise, use E2.

Now, if you just want three columns visible on Sheet1, right click and hide columns D and E.

[image: Sheet1]

Comment: Thanks! The difference is in Sheet 2. If Apt No is present there wont be a House no and vice versa. Key No is unique to either house or Apt not both.

Comment: @user3331363 Updated the pictures, is this correct now?

Comment: Sheet 2 is absolutely right. However in Sheet 1 column C & D are combined into one. So if I enter either Apt No or House No, Column C will display the key No.

Comment: @user3331363 Check the update - that would be my quick solution.  Otherwise, I'd just clean up all the code by making a UDF (User Defined Function) in an Excel Module

Comment: Thanks for your detailed description. This is really helpful. I really appreciate all you help. :)